# May "bundle install" update gems for rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

My bundle file contains gem descriptions like:

```
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'kaminari'
```

During the lapse of one year, these gems were updated, losing backward compatibility. After that, if I run `bundle install`  in a new machine that has no gems, I fear it will install all gems with the latest versions, and my code will break due to this.

Am I right? what is the solution to avoid this issue?

Comment: What is the problem _to try `bundle install` on the fresh machine and see_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I fear it will install all gems in latest versions and my code will break due to this.

If you've `Gemfile.lock` along with `Gemfile` `bundle install` doesn't break your code. The `Gemfile.lock` file is where Bundler records the exact versions that were installed (or must be installed). Otherwise you *might* have problems with versions dismiss.

Comment: Might be worth it noting that running `bundle update` instead of `bundle install` (or just `bundle`) will probably cause issues.

Comment: So, if someone accidentally ran bundle update, will he loss original gem versions? is it a good idea to specify exact versions in Gemfile?

Comment: versions in the Gemfile is a good idea, if someone accidentally ran bundle update and you don't use VCS you will loss original gem versions.

Comment: I would argue that you should avoid version numbers in the `Gemfile` because pinning gems in the `Gemfile` makes it very hard to update if you want or need to update your application. Furthermore, version numbers will be kept in the  `Gemfile.lock` anyway. If `bundle update` breaks your application, just restore the `Gemfile.lock` from version control.

Comment: @spickermann I prefer to set version in the Gemfile, don't have any problems with that.